# Split Text With Multiple Delimiters

Tags: c#, text, split, logic

Suggestion needed. Consider the below sample file with text passages.

```
1
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum at doming urbanitas mnesarchum. Eum ad paulo inermis. Iuvaret minimum mnesarchum ad mei. Dolores placerat pro ex.

Vel zril facete utamur et. Id dicam fuisset contentiones mea, vidisse sapientem consequuntur his ex. Vivendum liberavisse ut usu, mel habeo postea disputationi id. 
Timeam aliquid nec no, ex duo option dolorum appareat. Ut tota interesset vim, ne graeci principes sea. Mel et postulant repudiare, eos an populo appareat, 
qui placerat iudicabit instructior at. Qui sint malis an.


1 
2
Ne mutat putant omnium eos, cu duo malis molestie reprehendunt. Te duo adhuc posse graecis, inermis mediocrem sed te. 
Eam cu latine eruditi electram, populo nemore suscipit vim ei, hinc reformidans voluptatibus pri te. Ut suas sanctus epicurei eam, 
legimus luptatum ei duo. No mel recteque scriptorem referrentur, ne mel duis cetero consequat, id possit offendit mel.
2
3

3
4

Eu usu tamquam docendi, eum at facer semper sententiae, veritus deserunt ei vis. Id albucius insolens mea, sea ad amet nibh. 
Sed id epicuri luptatum liberavisse, mei etiam scripta no. Quod detracto ei qui, imperdiet posidonium in eos. 
4
:
:
N
:
N
```

The delimiter here being the sequence number of the passages itself.

(i.e)

> [Line Break]Number[Line Break]Passage[Line Break]Number[Line Break]

In what methods/ways could I split these passages into separate files faster, rather than iterating them line  by line.

Though I am right now working in C# and SQL, I also heard Phyton is much faster in these type of operations. So I can try any other options too.

EDIT: 
For sake of clarity, I gave them as text passages as examples. Those passages are actual instructions/input for other modules. To be more clear those passages would contain numbers.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good job for a regex. You could do this:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"(\b[0-9]+\b)(.*?)(\1)",RegexOptions.Singleline);
string s = ...
var result = regex.Matches(s)
                  .Cast<Match>()
                  .Select(m => m.Groups[2].Value.Trim(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray()))
                  .ToList();
```

- `(\b[0-9]+\b)`: match a word boundary, then match any numbers followed by a word boundary (prevent number being matched in middle of the text, added "1 1 1" in the first paragraph and the result stayed the same)
- `(.*?)`: match any character in a non-greedy way
- `(\1)`: match the number captured in the beginning (for safety, less chance the capture will stop at any random number in the paragraph)

[Demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%5b0-9%5d%2b)(.*%3f)(%5c1)&i=1%0d%0aLorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet%2c+cum+at+doming+urbanitas+mnesarchum.+Eum+ad+paulo+inermis.+Iuvaret+minimum+mnesarchum+ad+mei.+Dolores+placerat+pro+ex.%0d%0a%0d%0aVel+zril+facete+utamur+et.+Id+dicam+fuisset+contentiones+mea%2c+vidisse+sapientem+consequuntur+his+ex.+Vivendum+liberavisse+ut+usu%2c+mel+habeo+postea+disputationi+id.+%0d%0aTimeam+aliquid+nec+no%2c+ex+duo+option+dolorum+appareat.+Ut+tota+interesset+vim%2c+ne+graeci+principes+sea.+Mel+et+postulant+repudiare%2c+eos+an+populo+appareat%2c+%0d%0aqui+placerat+iudicabit+instructior+at.+Qui+sint+malis+an.%0d%0a%0d%0a%0d%0a1+%0d%0a2%0d%0aNe+mutat+putant+omnium+eos%2c+cu+duo+malis+molestie+reprehendunt.+Te+duo+adhuc+posse+graecis%2c+inermis+mediocrem+sed+te.+%0d%0aEam+cu+latine+eruditi+electram%2c+populo+nemore+suscipit+vim+ei%2c+hinc+reformidans+voluptatibus+pri+te.+Ut+suas+sanctus+epicurei+eam%2c+%0d%0alegimus+luptatum+ei+duo.+No+mel+recteque+scriptorem+referrentur%2c+ne+mel+duis+cetero+consequat%2c+id+possit+offendit+mel.%0d%0a2%0d%0a3%0d%0a%0d%0a3%0d%0a4%0d%0a%0d%0aEu+usu+tamquam+docendi%2c+eum+at+facer+semper+sententiae%2c+veritus+deserunt+ei+vis.+Id+albucius+insolens+mea%2c+sea+ad+amet+nibh.+%0d%0aSed+id+epicuri+luptatum+liberavisse%2c+mei+etiam+scripta+no.+Quod+detracto+ei+qui%2c+imperdiet+posidonium+in+eos.+%0d%0a4&o=s)

The result will take the strings captured by the 2nd group (`.*?`) and trim the linebreaks from the beginning and the end.

This will give a `List<string>` with elements:

`result[0]`:

> "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, cum at doming urbanitas mnesarchum. Eum ad paulo inermis. Iuvaret minimum mnesarchum ad mei. Dolores placerat pro ex.
>
> Vel zril facete utamur et. Id dicam fuisset contentiones mea, vidisse sapientem consequuntur his ex. Vivendum liberavisse ut usu, mel habeo postea disputationi id. 
>   Timeam aliquid nec no, ex duo option dolorum appareat. Ut tota interesset vim, ne graeci principes sea. Mel et postulant repudiare, eos an populo appareat, 
>   qui placerat iudicabit instructior at. Qui sint malis an."

`result[1]`:

> Ne mutat putant omnium eos, cu duo malis molestie reprehendunt. Te duo adhuc posse graecis, inermis mediocrem sed te. 
>   Eam cu latine eruditi electram, populo nemore suscipit vim ei, hinc reformidans voluptatibus pri te. Ut suas sanctus epicurei eam, 
>   legimus luptatum ei duo. No mel recteque scriptorem referrentur, ne mel duis cetero consequat, id possit offendit mel.

etc...

**Edit:**

If you want to filter out the empty paragraph you can do `.Where(str => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(str))` after the select. Then you'll only get 3 results.

Comment: Thanks for the demonstration. Just one question would this digit condition ([0-9]+) satisfy for sequences greater than 10 (double or three digit numbers) .

Comment: @madmonk88 yes, the `+` means match any number 0-9 at least one time and as many times as possible (so until something else than a number is met)

Comment: @madmonk88 Did an edit to the regex so the number has to be followed by a newline. If I now add `1 1 1` in the first paragraph for example, I still get the correct results.

Comment: Thanks for response. It works precise as intended with single digit sequences only. I am still tweaking it.

Comment: @madmonk88 For me it works with any number, are you sure you have the right regex?

Comment: Alex, I tweaked your regex and finally got satisfied all conditions with ([0-9]+)(.*[^\n]?)(\1) 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @madmonk88 Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Are you reading this from file or DB? In any case, if this will be stored in a string then you can use the split method:

[String.Split Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Its from word document or txt files and these files would vary in size. I need passages within the sequence numbers only. And iterating with Split takes times. I need method which has faster results irrespective of text size.

Comment: Unless your delimiter is something that will definitely not be contained in the text itself you will have a problem which ever approach you follow whether that is Split or Substring or even Regex.Split

Comment: For sake of clarity, I gave them as text passages. Those passages are actual instructions/input for other modules. To be more clear those passages would contain numbers.

Comment: And that is why i said it is not going to work. Your delimiter is not an actual delimiter.

Comment: The same argument I have made to high-ups but the files are from legacy platforms. And I am stuck with it. :(

Comment: Without being 100% sure...maybe you could try including the line breaks (\r\n) as part of your delimiter together with the number and using Regex.Split you might be able to pull it off

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Regex.Split`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.split%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to split by a pattern. If numbers do not occur in the passages, you can use "[0-9]+".

```
var passages = Regex.Split(text, "[0-9]+");
```

Comment: `[0-9]` will be a safer choice than `\d`; in case there're *more* than 9 chunks you have to use `[0-9]+` or `\\d+`

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Thanks for the hint. Answer is edited :)

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you can do it quite easily:

```
lines = filter(None, map(lambda l: l.strip(), open('text_file', mode='r').readlines()))
map(lambda item: open(item[0], 'w').write(item[1]), [lines[i:i + 2] for i in range(0, len(lines), 2)])
```

The 1st line reads everything to a list of strings that looks like this:
['1', 'passage 1 text', '2', 'passage 2 text', '3', 'passage 3 text', ...]

The 2nd line takes every 2 elements in the list and uses the first element as the file index and the second element as the text to write into the file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: tried your code, my first phyton execution, and got error pointing to second line other than that no other messages. Also in the file location, I can see files in the name of sequences but only the first is with text split and the remaining are empty. Tell me should I add anything more.

Comment: Could you share the error that you got? And also can you send a sample of the file?
I assume the file looks like this:
1
passage number 1   passage number 1   passage number 1   

2
passage number 2   passage number 2   passage number 2   

3
passage number 3   passage number 3   passage number 3   

4
passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4   passage number 4

Comment: I made below screenshots step by step. 
I think there is a fault in iteration but I cant correct it as I am sure of its syntax,sorry.

[Step 1](http://postimg.org/image/aqeak0wmr/)
[Step 2](http://postimg.org/image/feuaf7ltf/)
[Step 3](http://postimg.org/image/olcl2hr1v/)
[Step 4](http://postimg.org/image/5it7fkg1f/)

Comment: ok, not sure I understand the exact format. You got a few numbers there without any passages starting after it. For example, the number "1" is duplicate. So is number "2". "3" is a duplicate that is followed imminently by "4". My problem is that the syntax is not very coherent. I was expecting something like: Number, passage, number, passage and so on...